# When deciding a Primary Key, can I use Date part of a DateTime field

Tags: database-design, sql, sql-server, relational-database, winforms

I'm designing a payroll system I have designed a database with several tables and this question is related to following tables

`EMPLOYEE (Employee_ID [pk], Name,... etc)`
`LOCATION (Location_ID [pk], Name, Address, ...etc)`

These two tables have many to many relationship as one employee can work in several locations and in a location, several employees are working.

These two tables are related through `ATTENDANCE` table.

`ATTENDANCE (Employee_ID, Location_ID, Shift_Type, In, Out)`

Shift type would be either "Day" or "Night" and "In" / "Out" fields are `DateTime` fields. The shift type is decided based on the date in the field "In" . For example if an employee's `In` field is lets say -`06/22/2014 07:30:00 PM` then the shift type is `Night` and shift is belongs to 22/06/2014. (his `Out` time would be `23/06/2014 07:30AM`; that is on next day)

THE CONDITION is that, an Employee can't work same shift on same date twice even in two locations. But an employee can work Day in a location and Night in another location.

My initial primary key selection ATTENDANCE table was `(Employee_ID + In)` but that is wrong as an employee can work same shift in same day if the `In` time is slightly different in two occasions.

So now I know the primary key should be some thing like `(Employee_ID + Shift_Type + Shift_Date)`. But the problem is I don't have a Date field in the ATTENDANCE table. But I have `In` field which is a `DateTime` field.

Hopping that my understanding about the issue is correct...,

My question is, with out adding another field to ATTENDANCE table as `Shift_Date`, is there a possibility to get the Date part of the field `In`, when creating a `PRIMARY KEY` for this table ?

Comment: It's my personal opinion that composite primary keys are a terrible pain to deal with and they cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: I would create an auto number Attendance_ID field as my primary key then consider using constraints to enforce the business rules to ensure one employee isn't in two places at the same time.

Comment: A primary key is the wrong tool.  The purpose of a primary key is to establish identity.  It enforces uniqueness, sure, but that's just so that identities don't become indistinct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a date field as a primary key, but you can't key on PART of a field. You'd have to make a separate field with just the date.

This particular condition isn't something that would normally be enforced by building it into the primary key of a table anyway. Your "Employee can't work same shift on same date twice even in two locations" is a *business rule*, something that isn't necessarily going to be the same forever. (Goodness knows, there are entirely too many places out there that make their employees do split shifts...) A more typical way to handle this would be to just generate an auto-increment field for the primary key, and then enforce your business rules somewhere closer to the user interface.

Comment: Well said. A primary key is there to uniquely identify a record, not to enforce a business rule.

Comment: And who says an employee can't work the same shift more than once in a day?  Some disaster comes along, everyone leaves.  It becomes safe again, they return.  Or in a small town, there's a fire and some employees dash off to the fire station.